# Cisco Nexus 6k mac move detection not working

Tags: mac-address, cisco-nx-os, nx-os

My device is cisco Nexus 6001 Chassis (one unit dc switch)

```
# show version
...
kickstart: version 7.2(1)N1(1)
system:    version 7.2(1)N1(1)
...
```

I've configured mac move detection:

```
# conf t
# mac address-table notification mac-move
# logging level spanning-tree 6
# logging level fwm 6
# logging monitor 6
```

Looks like it is enabled:

```
 # show running-config | include move
 mac address-table notification mac-move
 # show logging level 
 Facility        Default Severity        Current Session Severity
 --------        ----------------        ------------------------
 ...
 fwm                     6                       6
 ...
 stp                     3                       6
 ...
```

But when I try to test this out (simply reconnect laptop on different ports of my switch), notifications are not sended to my logs.

The process of testing shown in picture:

[image]

Simply reconnecting between ports on downstream switches. The vlan is the same, so the mac is flaps between port on upstream NX-OS.

Maybe I've lost something important?

P.S. Maybe it is working when loop detection occurs.
Old cisco 7600 spams log messages a lot if mac flaps between intefaces.

P.S. Maybe there is problem in negative numbers.

```
 # show mac address-table notification mac-move
 MAC Move Notify Triggers: 2814884
   Number of MAC Addresses added: -1214153019 
   Number of MAC Addresses moved: 0 
   Number of MAC Addresses removed: -1214196878
```

Comment: At the point in time when you move the laptop (PC1) form SW1 to SW2, does the N6K still have a CAM table entry for PC1? Else it'll just be MAC learning when the first frame from PC1 arrives via SW2, and no mac move.

Comment: N6K seem to have a concept of _limit/threshold_ and _interval_ for mac-move notifications (see https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus6000/sw/command/reference/layer2/n6k-l2-cr/n6k-l2_cmds_m.html#pgfId-1375692) you may want to check if the given default values prevent syslog messages from being generated.

Comment: Yes it does have entry in CAM.

Comment: I was reading about limits but there are no information that it need to be activated for mac-move. ```# show mac address-table notification threshold 
MAC Move Threshold : disabled ```, but on cisco 7600 ```show mac address-table notification threshold 
    Status       limit        Interval  
  disabled        50           120``` it also disabled but working as expected.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: There is no correct answer ((, found id already and will provide it by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that mac move detection is workin a bit differently than on old IOS releases.

IOS every time drops log message when mac changes link where is nexus not. As the result mac move detection is exist and shows log message only when there are many flapping occurs between links. This is case where loops occur.

Generally I like old behaviour more than new one ;)

Answer (score 6):

Physically moving a device from port to port will not trigger a mac-move event. When you disconnect from port A, the link drops and all state is discarded -- including any known MACs on that port. Similarly, when you (re)connect to port B, no previous state is known; there's no latent knowledge of where that MAC has previously been.

A mac-move event will only be triggered if a known MAC is seen on a port where it is not known to be. [currently in the CAM tables] (eg. a wireless client roaming between APs.) The purpose is to detect attempts at spoofing -- i.e. I claim to have the MAC of the exchange server and trick machines into sending me that traffic.

Comment: The main problem that I disconnect laptop from downstream switches. I've edit my post to help understand problem.